# git: how to pull latest changes and resolve conflicts

Tags: git, github, conflict, pull

I want to pull in all the latest changes from a github repo. There is only one branch and only one person (the developer) adds and modifies the code. I simply pull everything in, once a new feature is added.

Normally, all I do is:

```
git pull
```

But this time I got an error message which reads:

> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the results.

I'd simply like to pull in the latest changes from the repo. I'm not sure why there are conflicts when only one person is responsible for this repo.

Note: I don't want to commit anything to the repo.

Comment: It means that code on your local machine is different from what you pull from github. So, either go to each file the message (probably) points you and resolve the conflicts as it hints you and then make the `git pull` again or (longer one) just make another clone of the repo.

Comment: ahh I see. Is there a way I can tell git to ignore everything from my local machine and keep everything from the remote repo?

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: unfortunately not, still says to "fix conflicts and then commit the results".

Comment: neither :( something strange is going on.

Comment: You must be a n00b if you're spelling it newb..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, if you just watch the repo and do not change the files (or do not want your changes to remain after update) do:

`git reset --hard HEAD` followed by `git pull`.

This must overwrite the code on your local machine with code from github repo.

Another option would be
`git fetch --all` followed by `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: not sure what I was doing before but this magically worked! thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. `git pull` = `git fetch` + `git merge`.
2. Things went wrong in the second half, the `git merge`.
3. For `git merge` to choose not to do a "fast forward" instead of a real merge, someone (perhaps the developer, perhaps you) has to have done something unusual.
4. Only a real merge can have merge conflicts,

So, the solution to the problem lies in figuring out the "something unusual" and/or the person involved.

Note that if you are actively making *your own* changes, the merge conflict is not unusual after all.  I'm taking you at your word that you have not done your own `git commit`s.

In any case, the first thing to do (if you don't want to just re-clone everything from scratch) is to terminate the conflicted merge, so that you're back to where you would be if you had used `git fetch` and not also used `git merge`.  (You did use both, via `git pull`, and it was the `merge` that failed.)  To end the attempt to merge, since you're in this state where it failed, you can just use:

```
git merge --abort
```

Next, it's probably worth figuring out why git wants to do a merge in the first place.  The easiest way to do that is to run these two commands:

```
git fetch
git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all
```

The `log` will show you where *your* branch—probably named `master`—ends, and where the "remote" (`origin/master`) ends.  (The `git fetch` step is just in case you're using an older git, where `git pull` runs `git fetch` in such a way that it skips a step, which will make the `git log` output misleading.)

If you see something like this:

```
* f96824d (HEAD, master) some commit message
* d1574b8 (origin/master) another commit message
* b9491ea a third commit message
...
```

this means you have a commit they don't.<sup>1</sup>  If you see:

```
* 676699a (origin/master) here a commit message
| * 9124325 (HEAD, master) there a commit message
|/
* a19ce3f everywhere a commit message
...
```

then again, you have a commit they don't.

If *you* did not make this (or these) commit(s), *they* must have *retracted* some commit(s).  You have them because you grabbed them at some point, with an earlier `git fetch`, and then put them on your `master` branch with an earlier `git merge`.  But they've retracted these commit(s), and then perhaps made more new ones.  With your latest `git merge` you're asking git to combine their old commit(s) and their new ones, and those are conflicting.

In both cases you can simply force your `master` to move to the same commit as their `origin/master`, with:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

The `reset` command means "take whatever my current branch is"—in this case, `master`—"and make it point to the exact same commit as I name here: `origin/master`".  The `--hard` means "and also, throw away my current work-tree and replace it with the one attached to the commit I'm moving to now."

---

The normal case—normal for your setup anyway—is that they can have commit(s) that you don't, but every commit you have, they also have.  In this case your `git merge` sees that it can simply "slide your branch up" to match theirs, which is a "fast forward" operation.  In cases like that, the `git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline` (the order of these options does not matter) output looks more like:

```
* 7cf123a (origin/master) lots of twisty
* b9cce10 little commit messages,
* 009cda1 (HEAD, master) all somewhat alike
...
```

In this case, just imagine that the labels (`HEAD, master`) are slid up along the lines connecting the `*`s.  (The actual lines are too small to draw here—there's just not enough room between lines—but `git log --graph --all --decorate` will show them: this time we leave out `--oneline` so there are more lines; as will graphical viewers like `gitk`.  As shown above, in some cases there is some room for lines, which `git log` draws with `|` and `/` characters and such.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, if you see this, you should just get an `everything up to date` from your `git merge`, and hence no conflict.  So I'm expecting something like the 2nd one.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation! My "git log --graph --all --decorate" looks like your 2nd set up, where Head, master is under origin/master. now what should I do as Im still getting the merge error.

Comment: The "what to do" is already there above: if you're sure you want to discard the commit that `master` points-to, use `git reset` to make `master` point to the same commit as `origin/master`.  (The `HEAD` name normally points to another name, in this case `master`, so there's no need to do anything to `HEAD` itself.  Re-point `master` and `HEAD` automatically follows.)  Remember to use `--hard` if you want the work-tree updated too (you almost certainly do).

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation, I now have a better idea of what certain things are doing!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting conflicts because you have made some commits on the local repo which conflicts with what is pushed on the origin.

There can be multiple ways to solve this.

1. Reset the local repo with origin. 
   Assuming your branch name is master. First download all the server changes with git fetch and just repoint your current branch to origin branch with reset hard.

   git fetch --all
   git reset --hard origin/master
2. Resolve the conflicts in the file and then commit them back again.
   Check the files that are in conflict. Add them to index after you have resolved the conflicts and then commit the changes.

   git add

   git commit -m

Comment: Boosted_d16 probably has a pre-1.8.4 (or is it 1.8.5?) version of git, so that `git pull` prevents `git fetch` from updating the `origin/master` label.  In this case, step (1) won't help without an initial `git fetch` to get the label updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following way

```
git fetch origin // that will pull all the updates for all the branches
git checkout <branch>
// either of these two below
git pull origin <branch> 
// if the above command does not work and shows you conflicts
// to get rid off from conflicts try this
git reset --hard origin/<branch>
```